# How to move the icon on an EditText on Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I just added an icon to my EditText, but unfortunately I can't move it further to the right, what can I do?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/inserisciNumero"
android:hint="Numero di telefono"
android:layout_width="321dp"
android:layout_height="46dp"
android:drawableStart="@drawable/iconatelefono"
android:drawablePadding="12dp"
android:background="@drawable/sottofondoedit"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="36dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="183dp" />
```

[image]

Comment: Please embed images into the posts where possible, instead of providing links to images. That makes your question presentable and easy to read

Comment: @HoRn unfortunately I can't because of my poor reputation

Comment: Oh yes, here's the post about that https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268469/why-cant-users-with-less-than-10-reputation-points-add-images-while-asking-ques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add start padding as follows:

```
android:paddingStart="12dp"
```

This will move everything to the right in your *EditText* including the drawable.